# product of random variables with different distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

This assignment is from an old exam I'm doing for practice before taking the real exam.

Let $X \sim N(0,1)$ and let $Y$ be independent of $X$ with $P(Y=1) = P(Y=0) = 1/2$. Let $Z = XY$.

a) What is the distribution of $Z$ (distributions function or density) and what is the class of that distribution?

I simply don't know where to start. I'm pretty sure $Y$ has the Bernoulli distribution, but I have no idea how to calculate the product of two distributions when one is discrete and the other continuous. Any hints?

Comment: I am sure someone else will supply the math, but intuitively, how would you expect the distribution to behave? Such thinking may help greatly with formulating a more rigorous answer.

Comment: What is the value of $Z=XY$ when $Y=0$? What it the value of $Z=XY$ when $Y=1$?

Comment: I think the biggest problem for me in this course it is hard for me to think intuitively about distributions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual trick uses the following identity

$$P(Z\leq z) = \mathbb{E}[P(Z\leq z|Y)],$$

where the expectation on the right hand side is with respect to $Y$. We have

\begin{align*}
P(XY\leq z) &= \mathbb{E}[P(XY\leq z|Y)]\\
&= P(X\cdot 0\leq z|Y=0)P(Y=0) + P(X\cdot 1\leq z|Y=1)P(Y=1)\\
&= P(0\leq z|Y=0)P(Y=0) + P(X\leq z|Y=1)P(Y=1)\\
&= P(0\leq z)P(Y=0) + P(X\leq z)P(Y=1)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\cdot\boldsymbol{1}_{\{0\leq z\}} + \frac{1}{2}\Phi(z).
\end{align*}

We see that the distribution function has a jump/discontinuity at $z=0$. This was to be expected, because when $Y=0$, the variable $Z=XY$ becomes a discrete variable, while for $Y=1$, $Z=XY$ is still a continuous variable. This is the reason why the distribution function is split into a discrete and a continuous part.

Comment: I sort of understand what you did, but since it feels really important that I truly understand this, I will ask some more questions if that is ok. 

1) When you went from $P(0\leq z | Y = 0)P(Y=0) + P(0\leq z |Y=1)P(Y=1)$ to $P(0\leq z)P(Y=0) + P(X\leq z)P(Y=1)$, what was the reasoning behind that? You basically removed the $|Y=0$ part, and I'm not sure why one can do that.

2) I'm also not sure about the last row and how to think about the indicator function. It says that it is 1 when $0 \leq z$, but why? 

Sorry if my questions are a little dumb but I am pretty dumb so it is to be expected.

Comment: What he's using there is $P(A|B)P(B) = P(A\cap B) = P(A) P(B)$ where the first equality is from the definition of conditional probability and the second from indepenence of $A$ and $B$

Comment: @m.bing maybe you already have your answer, but let me include mine as well just to be safe. I can go from $P(0\leq z|Y=0)$ to $P(0\leq z)$, because the two events $(0\leq z)$ and $(Y=0)$ are independent, and similarly, I can go from $P(X\leq z | Y=1)$ to $P(X\leq z)$, because the events $(X\leq z)$ and $(Y=1)$ are independent (which is a consequence of $X$ and $Y$ being independent random variables). Note that $(0\leq z)$ is a weird event. It is not even random. I fixed a $z$ to begin with, and either $0\leq z$ or not, there is no underlying stochastics to this.

Comment: @m.bing Because there is no randomness to the event $0\leq z$, its probability $P(0\leq z)$ is either $1$ or $0$ depending on whether the event happens or not. Suppose that $z=2$. Then $0\leq 2$ is a true statement, and the probability of a true statement is $1$. On the other hand, if $z<0$, then $0\leq z$ is false, and the probability of a false statement is $0$. This is why I use the indicator function, i.e. $P(0\leq z) = \boldsymbol{1}_{\{0\leq z\}}$.

Comment: Now I understand completely!

Answer (score 2):

To supply HowDoIMath's answer, a more intuitive approach (since intuition is what is lacking):

We need the distribution of $Z$, i.e. we want to know $$P(Z<z)$$

That can be rewritten as $$P(XY<z)$$

Now we observe when does $XY$ fall under the value $z$. We know that if $Y=1$, the distribution will be
$$P(X<z)$$
Which is simply the normal distribution! But what happens when $Y=0$? Then we have the distribution
$$P(0<z)$$
Which equals $0$ if $z\leq 0$ and $1$ if $z>0$

Thanks to the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, we can now conclude that each one of these will happen with probability of $\frac 12$, which is exactly the same answer as HowDoIMath's. Note that this is a very heuristic solution and refer to HowDoIMath's answer for a "proper" solution.

Comment: That was of great help and answered the question I had in the comment to HowDoIMath's answer about the indicator function.

Answer (score 1):

The joint "density" of $(X,Y)$ is given by the product of the conditional density of $X\mid Y$ with the marginal density of $Y$:
\begin{align}
f_{X,Y}(x,y) &= f_{X\mid Y=y}(x\mid Y=y)f_Y(y)\\
&= f_X(x)f_Y(y) \tag{by independence } \\
&= \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac12 x^2} \left ((1-p)\mathsf 1_{\{0\}}(y) + p \mathsf 1_{\{1\}}(y)\right).
\end{align}
(We can assume $Y\sim\operatorname{Ber}(p)$ where $0<p<1$ since $p=\frac12$ doesn't change the result.) The reason I write "density" with quotes is because $X$ is an absolutely continuous random variable, i.e. the density of $X$ is with respect to Lebesgue measure, while $Y$ is a discrete random variable, i.e. the density of $Y$ is with respect to counting measure. Note that if we integrate $f_{X,Y}$ with respect to $x$ we get

\begin{align}
\int f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ \mathsf dx &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac12 x^2}\left ((1-p)\mathsf 1_{\{0\}}(y) + p \mathsf 1_{\{1\}}(y)\right)  \mathsf dx\\
&= \left ((1-p)\mathsf 1_{\{0\}}(y) + p \mathsf 1_{\{1\}}(y)\right)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac12 x^2}\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \left ((1-p)\mathsf 1_{\{0\}}(y) + p \mathsf 1_{\{1\}}(y)\right)\\
&= f_Y(y),
\end{align}
the marginal density of $Y$, and similarly integrating the joint density with respect to $y$ yields the marginal density of $X$, as
$$\int_\mu f_Y = (1-p)\mu(\{0\}) + p\mu(\{1\}) = 1, $$
where $\mu$ is counting measure.